# Codeigniter array input filed not working

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms, codeigniter

I have a scenario in my project module which allows user to enter as many values as he wants in a form. I have given an array name to the field but when i try to get these values in my controller then it only returns the first value of the array. I have used java-script to append new input fields dynamically.

I can't figure out what mistake i am making.

Here is My code.

**My view**

```
<h1> <small>Order Details</small></h1>
<table class="table " id="dynamic_field">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="product_name[]" id="name" class="form-control name_list" placeholder="Product Name">
        </td>
        <td>  
            <button type="button"  name="submit" id="add" class="btn btn-  success">Add More</button>
        </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1;
$('#add').click(function(){
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="product_name[]" id="last_class" class="form-control name_list" placeholder="Product Name"></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove" name="remove" id="'+i+'"> X</button></td></tr>')
});
$(document).on('click','.btn_remove',function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#row"+button_id+"").remove();
});
</script>
```

When i try to print out the input field array using `print_r` it only returns the first value of the array even though we might have added more than 1 input fields.

Comment: Also add your controller code

Answer (score 0):

**Change your script and check**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var j = 1;
 var i = 1;

  $('#add').click(function()
  {
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="product_name['+ j +']" id="last_class" class="form-control name_list" placeholder="Product Name"></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove" name="remove" id="'+i+'"> X</button></td></tr>');

j++ ;
  });


    $(document).on('click','.btn_remove',function()
    {
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#row"+button_id+"").remove();

    });



</script>
```

Comment: In controller :- $this->input->post('product_name');

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller

```
$names=$this->input->post('product_name') ;
foreach($names as $pname) {
            echo $pname; 
    }
```